# WxWidgets: do I need to run MainLoop when using only modals?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm using wxWdigets (wxPython to be exact) to display some modal dialogs.

This page https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.EventLoopBase.html says:

> Temporary event loops are usually created by wx.Dialog.ShowModal .

So while I still need to create the `wx.App` object to initialize the window system, my understanding is that if I only use modal dialogs then I don't need to call the `MainLoop` on the `wx.App` object.

In practice not calling `MainLoop` seems to work fine - however I wasn't able to find a definitive answer in the wx Documentation.

My specific worry is that `MainLoop` might be doing some cleanup when it exits, which I would be missing by not invoking it.

So my question: is it necessary to call `MainLoop` when using only modals?

Comment: you don't need to run extra event loop. In fact there is a very few scenarios where the external event loop will need to be run by the wxWidgets library user (probably 0.1% of use cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to run the main event loop if you only need to show a modal dialog. However you still need to initialize the library, which is typically done by creating the `wxApp` object, so you still have to do this.